# CRM (2015/3/6) Plugins on SSRS Reports

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2015

We have a situation where we need to modify the data being returned by CRM. This was implemented within the application using plug-ins so every aspect of user interaction was managed.

However, in SSRS reports, these plug-ins are not being called. We have investigated a number of other messages (such as execute), but haven't really come up with a viable solution as of yet. A post here which suggested the use of javascript code is not viable since we have a large number of reports.

If there is anyone who has insight on this please let me know. TIA.

Answer (score 2):

You are not the only person who scratched head trying to figure out why it happens and after investigating their reporting extension I discovered that data is fetched directly from SQL without usage of endpoint (so plugins are not triggered). FetchXml internally transformed to SQL.

Comment: thanks for your comment. can you describe how exactly you were able to come to this conclusion? Which version did you test this against? is it on CRM Online or on premise? I plan to describe this to my client so they can understand as well.

Comment: It was 4 years ago. It was 2011 version of CRM On-Prem. Conclusions were made after analysis of FetchXml connection reporting component with .Net reflector. I don't believe that anything changed radically on that side. Also I believe that there is no big difference between CRM On-Prem and Online in reporting part.

Comment: thanks for your response -- gives me something to go on with.